# command to layout tab separated list nicely

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csv, tabulation

Sometimes, I'm getting as an input tab separated list, which is not quite aligned, for instance

```
var1  var2  var3
var_with_long_name_which_ruins_alignment  var2 var3
```

Is there an easy way to render them aligned?

```
var1                                      var2  var3
var_with_long_name_which_ruins_alignment  var2  var3
```

Comment: Someone could make a solution based on elastic tabstops: http://nickgravgaard.com/elastictabstops/

Comment: See also: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294 and http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/

Comment: And a Go implementation: http://golang.org/pkg/tabwriter/

Comment: Tried piping it to `column -t`?

Comment: @alex, that's what I was looking for. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: Tucked away at the end of Mikel's perl answer is the clincher comment (by Mikel)... *`columns -t`* acts on general whitespace. To work with **tabs only**, use *`column -t -s $'\t'`*

Answer (score 64, accepted):

So, the answer becomes:

```
column -t file_name
```

Note that this splits columns at *any* whitespace, not just tabs. If you want to split on tabs only, use:

```
column -t -s $'\t' -n file_name
```

The `-s $'\t'` sets the delimiter to tabs only and `-n` preserves empty columns (adjacent tabs).

P.S.: Just want to point out that the credit goes to [Alex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1946/alex) as well. The original hint was provided by him as a comment to the question, but was never posted as an answer.

Comment: I'll wait a bit for Alex to get the credit, I think he deserves it. If he wouldn't answer in a few days I'll accept an answer from somebody else.

Comment: Sure! I too was unaware of `column` :)

Comment: This seems ideal but unfortunately `column` seems to fail when it encounters empty cells. See [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29023/21014). Depending on which version of `column` you have, you may be able to specify the `-n` option to correct this.

Comment: Also, this command will not only split on tabs, but also on "any whitespace". To split just on tabs, use `column -t -s $'\t'`.

Comment: @Fritz why we have to use $?

Comment: The `$` before a single quote `'` expands escape sequences in the following string. In this case `'\t'` is a string of two characters: bachslash (ASCII 0x5C) followed by `t` (ASCII 0x74). But `$'\t'` contains only one character: a Tab (ASCII 0x09), because the escape sequence `\t` (which stands for "tab") is expanded to an actual tab character. You can try this using hexdump: Try `echo -n '\t' | hd` vs. `echo -n $'\t' | hd`.

Answer (score 4):

For manual tab stops: `expand -t 42,48`

For automatic tab stops, as suggested by [alex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1946/alex): `column -t`

(`expand` is on all [POSIX systems](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expand.html). `column` is a BSD utility, available in many Linux distributions as well, thanks to [util-linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html).)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script to do it:

**aligntabs.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $delim = '\s*\t\s*';

my %length = ();
my @lines = ();
for my $line (<>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @words = split $delim, $line;
    my $numwords = scalar(@words);
    for my $i (0..$numwords-1) {
        my $maxlen = $length{$i} // 0;
        my $thislen = length($words[$i]);
        $maxlen = ($thislen > $maxlen)? $thislen: $maxlen;
        $length{$i} = $maxlen;
    }
    push @lines, [@words];
}

foreach my $wordsref (@lines) {
    my @words = @$wordsref;
    my $numwords = scalar(@words);
    for my $i (0..$numwords-1) {
        if ($i < $numwords-1) {
            my $fieldlen = $length{$i};
            printf "%-${fieldlen}s ", $words[$i];
        }
        else {
            print $words[$i];
        }
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

**usage**

```
$ aligntabs.pl < infile
var1                                     var2 var3
var_with_long_name_which_ruins_alignment var2 var3
```

Comment: Um, thanks, but I was hoping there's a more "portable" way to do that.

Comment: Me too!  Couldn't find one.  `pr` and `nl` are the two basic tools for the formatting, and after that `awk`, `sed`, `perl`, etc.

Comment: it's as simple as `column`

Comment: @Elzar Excellent!  `column -t -s $'\t'` seems to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Peter.O's comment which is what I wanted to align (tab delimited data, TSV), this phrase works very nicely:

```
column -t -s $'\t' /Users/me/data.csv | less --chop-long-lines
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/||/| |/g;s/||/| |/g' filename-here | column -s"|" -t | less -#2 -N -S
```

Explanation:

Sed will add a space between blank delimters

Column will add equal spacing between the columns

```
zydsld|asl|asd
das|aosdk|dd
```

becomes

```
zydsld|asl  |asd
das   |aosdk|dd
```

Less will open the output in a file viewer. -N and -S will add line number and disable wrapping respectively

Comment: Elegant and works cleanly!!!

Answer (score 1):

With Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc) you have pretty print output.

Run

```
mlr --inidx --ifs "\t" --opprint cat input | tail -n +2
```

to have

```
var1                                     var2 var3
var_with_long_name_which_ruins_alignment var2 var3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) in a slightly different way from what's done in [aborruso's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495416/116858):

```bash
$ mlr --t2p cat file
var1                                     var2 var3
var_with_long_name_which_ruins_alignment var2 var3
```

This reads the data as a TSV (tab-separated values) file, and simply outputs it in a pretty-printed table form.  The `--t2p` option to `mlr` is short-hand for `--itsv` (input TSV) and `--opprint` (output pretty-printed) together.

With borders:

```bash
$ mlr --t2p --barred cat file
+------------------------------------------+------+------+
| var1                                     | var2 | var3 |
+------------------------------------------+------+------+
| var_with_long_name_which_ruins_alignment | var2 | var3 |
+------------------------------------------+------+------+
```

As a markdown table:

```bash
$ mlr --t2m cat file
```

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| var_with_long_name_which_ruins_alignment | var2 | var3 |