# How to display TSV (csv) in console, when empty cells are missed by: `column -t -s $'\t' `

Tags: text-processing, csv, spreadsheet

I have file with columns spearated with `tab`.

I have file when some rows have empty cells (on begining, in middle).

In such cases `column -t -s $'\t'` simply fails:

Input:

```
$ echo -e 'A\tB\tC\tD\n\tb1\t\td1\n\t\t\td2\na3\t\t\td3' > in.tsv
$ hexdump -C in.tsv 
00000000  41 09 42 09 43 09 44 0a  09 62 31 09 09 64 31 0a  |A.B.C.D..b1..d1.|
00000010  09 09 09 64 32 0a 61 33  09 09 09 64 33 0a        |...d2.a3...d3.|
0000001e
```

column output:

```
$ cat in.tsv | column -t -s $'\t'
A   B   C  D
b1  d1
d2
a3  d3
```

instead of:

```
A       B       C       D
        b1              d1
                        d2
a3                      d3
```

Could you recommend how to do TSV command line formatting ? (in Unix way, I want to pipe output of program into formatter, like `column`)

Any way of "fixing" `column` approach? Maybe another tool?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just use Debian's `column`. It provides the option `-n` which makes it work exactly how you want.

Alternatively, you can put a space in the empty columns, using `sed`:

```
sed ':x s/\(^\|\t\)\t/\1 \t/; t x' < in.tsv | column -t -s $'\t'
```

example:

```
$ sed ':x s/\(^\|\t\)\t/\1 \t/; t x' < in.tsv | column -t -s $'\t'
A   B   C  D
    b1     d1
           d2
a3         d3
```

Comment: I am afraid how sed will behave with alternative '^\|\t'... due to '^' is not specifying atoms. (So, is it going to substitute `\1` with empty string?

Comment: Yes, `\(^\)` alone matches an empty string, anchored to the beginning of line. `\1` "produces a copy" of that empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/||/| |/g;s/||/| |/g' filename-here
```

The above command is for pipe so replace it with tabspace.

You just need to replace empty columns with a blank space and pipe the output to the command you are already using.