# Layout tab/spaces

Tags: text-processing, command-line, csv

I've read this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7718/256195, that only if `var` doesn't contain any tab/spaces but in my case it does contain spaces, like below example:

```
"this is a test"      this_is_a_solid_line_that_doesnot_contain_tab_or_spaces
```

command `column` will separate `this` `is` ..etc also, but I'd want something acts on only `"this is a test"` and `this_is_a_solid_line_that_doesnot_contain_tab_or_spaces`.

Purpose: I have a bunch of lines like above in a file that don't be aligned properly.

Comment: Are the fields tab-delimited?

Comment: Possibly of some help (if the fields are tab-delimited): [Align columns evenly without "column - t"](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/484390)

Comment: Thanks, what would it be when I'm using pipeline like: `cat file | somethine_here_to_filter`, what would your script will be put after a pipeline?

Comment: The shell script in the second half of my answer expects a filename, so `./script.sh file`.  To make it work on a pipe, use `something-that-produces-data | ./script.sh /dev/stdin`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I tried but with `var1  test` it produces `"var1.................................................................test"` that somehow treat spaces as tab.

Comment: Nobody yet knows what delimiter your input uses, and I don't know what command you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input doesn't contain `|` characters, you could convert those sequences of whitespace that are not inside quotes to `|` (or any other character that doesn't occur in the input) and then pipe to `column -ts'|'`:

```
<input.txt perl -lpe 's/(".*?")|\s+/$1||"|"/ge' | column -ts'|'
```

Comment: This is golden. I've just tested against this and achieved the question in simple and elegant way.