# Properly tabulating 'find's output with printf and sorting them by date

Tags: command-line, find, output

I'm using `gfind` running on MacOS, to find text files.

I am trying to see the filenames only and the birthdate of my `gfind` results, and then sorting them by date, and paging them. Is this achievable?

For the moment I am trying `gfind . -name "*.txt" -printf "%f \t\t %Bc\n"`

But the results are the following:

```
todo.txt         Fri Mar  4 17:47:41 2022
99AC1EF5-6BE3-556B-8254-84A8764819E0.txt         Fri Mar  4 17:49:08 2022
chrome_shutdown_ms.txt       Fri Mar  4 17:48:07 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:05 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:05 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:06 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:47:46 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:01 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:01 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:05 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:05 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:06 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:06 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:47:46 2022
index.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:06 2022
LICENSE.txt          Fri Mar  4 17:48:07 2022
english_wikipedia.txt        Fri Mar  4 17:48:07 2022
female_names.txt         Fri Mar  4 17:48:07 2022
male_names.txt       Fri Mar  4 17:48:07 2022
```

Is there a way to tabulate the output in order to show some consistency as to what it looks like ? I would like to only show the filenames and the birthdate in a more elegant way.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: [Command to layout tab separated list nicely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7698/108618).

Comment: Using the suggestion in the (currently) accepted answer of the duplicate question: `gfind . -name '*.txt' -printf '%f|%Bc\n' | column -t -s '|'` (`|` is any character not present in any filename).

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Kusalananda!! This actually worked **flawlessly**. I could not thank you enough.

Comment: @Kusalananda, now that I have you here; do you know where's good documentation on where and why the dollar sign before a single quote expands escape sequences? This is the fist time I hear about this, and I'm googling about it, but all I find is examples of people wanting to escape the dollar sign. Thanks again!

Comment: In the `bash` manual, look for the section called "QUOTING". The `$'...'` quoting is described a bit down there. The "ANSI C" quoting `$'...'` in the `zsh` shell is more or less the same as in `bash` but the manual is harder to read. See also various post on this site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ansi+c%22+quoting+ Possibly a good start: [Which shells support ANSI-C quoting? e.g. $'string'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371873)

Comment: Thanks again for your time and explanation @Kusalananda! This is very valuable info for me! I will carefully read those links in order to understand this better. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can use:

```
gfind . -name '*.txt' -printf '%-40f %Bc\n'
```

or

```
gfind . -name '*.txt' -printf '%40f %Bc\n'
```

To print the file name left-aligned or right-aligned padded with spaces to a length of 40 bytes (not characters, nor columns unfortunately).

That would align them as long as file names don't contain control, multi-byte, zero-width or double-width characters, are are not longer than 40 bytes.

Note that if you put the date first (here using the mtime (%T), not the Btime (%B) which I doubt is what you want as it doesn't reflect anything useful in the life of the file), and use a more useful and unambiguous timestamp format like the standard YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS[.subsecond]+ZZZZ, then you don't have to worry about alignment and it makes the sorting easier:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -printf '%TFT%TT%Tz %f\n'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time for such a detailed comment! @Stéphane! Your take actually looks more streamlined, since I don't have to pipe the output. I did notice the special chars messing up with the output but I can live with that.
One last Q: If I use the `mtime`and then make any modifications for the file, how can I still see the file 'creation date' so to speak? Thanks again!